# VBA in Word always sets textbox indents to same wrong value

Tags: vba, ms-word, textbox

I'm trying to create a textbox in Word using VBA, but Word consistently createst the textbox with left and right indents about 5 inches apart, indented about 1 inch from each side. I've tried everything I can think of - setting the indents myself (failed), clearing all paragraph formatting first (failed), clearing all tab stops (failed), and resetting the left/right indents a second time at the end of my code.

I can see the tab stops when I click in the created text box, and if I manually move them the text inside responds appropriately. Does anyone know what am I doing wrong (or not doing)? The `ShapeTboxCreate` subroutine just creates teh text box normally, but converts the parameters (in inches) to points before passing them to the `.Shapes.AddShape(msoTextBox,...)` function.

Thank you.

```
   Set tbox = ShapeTboxCreate(0.5, 0.37, 7.5, 0.75)
   tbox.name = "Header Title Box"
   selection.ClearParagraphAllFormatting
   selection.Collapse wdCollapseStart
   tbox.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.ClearAll
   tbox.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = 0
   tbox.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.RightIndent = 0
   tbox.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "My Text Here"
```

Here is the subroutine. It converts the parameters (in inches) to points and creates the rectangle.

```
Function ShapeRectCreate(left As Single, top As Single, width As Single, _
   height As Single) As Shape
Dim shp As Shape
Set shp = ActiveDocument.shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 0, 0, _
      InchesToPoints(width), InchesToPoints(height))
shp.RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage
shp.RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
shp.left = InchesToPoints(left)
shp.top = InchesToPoints(top)
Set ShapeRectCreate = shp
End Function
```

Comment: Just a note for future reference: You appear to be using some kind of library: `ShapeTboxCreate` is *not* part of Word's object model. Something is providing this for you, whether it's a function you've written, or some kind of add-in. When you ask a question and provide code with something that's not standard we *cannot* know what that is, cannot test and cannot help. For this reason, your Answer is also meaningless for anyone else because your environment is special, not standard.

Comment: Agreed. That's why I provided the code below, within a few minutes of posting the original question. I posted it as an answer instead of modifying the original question. If you could say a few words on what the difference is between the (apparently) two different kinds of text boxes created by the lines below, and why an ellipse / smiley face shows up with a little yellow dot in the rectangle, it would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I'd look at it, but you need to provide the FULL code that's causing the behavior - not just ellipses where parameters go. And better to incorporate this *in* your question and alter the question. FWIW to me, it sounds as if AutoCorrect were kicking in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the code that created the text box. This code looks like it should work, but it created an ellipse with a smiley face in it, embedded in the text box. The tabs were set by the smiley face character. Totally weird, I know.

```
ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddShape(msoTextBox,...)
```

When I replaced the code above with this code, everything worked as expected:

```
ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal,...)
```

Maybe this might help someone someday.